# How to bypass a redirecting script using scripy

Tags: python, forms, scrapy

I would like to **scrape** a website to retrieve some datas, but I am facing this script:

```
var SITE='winedecider.com';
var URL1=document.URL;
var URL2=URL1.replace('http://','').replace('www.','');
console.log(URL1);
console.log(URL2);
console.log(URL2.substring(0, SITE.length));
if (URL2.substring(0, SITE.length)==='winedecider.com') {
 console.log('OK');
}
else {
 console.log('URL non autorisée');
 window.location='http://mediaplanning.fr/redirect.php?r=2613&d=&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com'
}
```

It prevents me from scraping the data which are inside the form right after this script.
[image]
Does someone know how to bypass this script to acces the infos that are inside the form post request?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: If the JavaScript logic is consistent, you could extract the target URL from the response using regular expressions, and yield a request for it.